# Is it possible to use LIMIT with a subquery result?

Tags: mysql, sql

When the last rows of an ordered set are required, it is usual to create a derived table and reorder. For example, to return the last 3 elements of a table with an auto incremented `id`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
) t ORDER BY t.id
```

Since `LIMIT` can also have an offset, the same result could be achieved if we know the number of lines (say 10) in advance with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 3 OFFSET 7
```

Is it possible to run a subquery to `count(*)` a table and dynamically build a `LIMIT` using that number?

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 3 OFFSET [ select count() -3 ]
```

Comment: No, the `LIMIT` parameters have to be literals, they can't be expressions. If you need to calculate the limit dynamically, you'll have to do it in a prepared query in a stored procedure, or do it in the client language.

Comment: I'm thinking outloud here, but you probably could use `HAVING` with `COUNT()`. I'd have to test that theory out though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149708/using-as-to-avoid-same-query-mysql/41150070#41150070

Comment: Thank you @Fred-ii- ! I think I see what you mean, and made me think that something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > (SELECT count(id) FROM table)-3` also works although it is very specific to a case where all `id`s are present and continuously auto incremented. Not much flexible to other text possibilities that the original one works for as well.

Comment: @sidyll You're welcome. Your above comment's code could also work in your favor where it could be modified to work dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to specify a dynamic offset.

Your original query with a subquery is the easiest way to do this.